# Ncrack just do nothing after launching command

Tags: nmap

I am pentesting my host using ncrack

I use such command `ncrack -U login.txt -P pass.txt -iL ipList.txt -p 3389`

After launching it shows me that *ncrack has started* and nothing happens.
What is the problem please help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about software development

Answer (score 0):

This question should be on [Security Stackexchange](http://security.stackexchange.com). Anyway, try to change `3389` for `rdp`.

You can try too removing the list using only one ip to test:

`ncrack -vv -U login.txt -P pass.txt x.x.x.x:3389` where x.x.x.x is one of the ips of your list. With -vv you will see more verbose output to find out the error.

Are you sure your ips and/or hostnames on ipList.txt are accesible by network on tcp port 3389?

If not, it is a network problem.